# How do I adjust the Entire image using jython

Tags: python, jython, jes

```
def whiteBalance():
 myFile = pickAFile()
 print myFile
 myPicture = makePicture(myFile)
 print myPicture
 explore(myPicture)
 xRef = requestInteger("Enter the X Value of the Reference Point")
 yRef = requestInteger("Enter the Y value of the Reference Point")
   for p in getPixels(myPicture):
     average = (getRed(p)+getGreen(p)+getBlue(p))/3
     setColor(p,makeColor(average,average,average))
       for px in getPixels(myPicture):
          newRed = getRed(px) * 0.9
          newGreen = getGreen(px) * 0.944
          newBlue = getBlue(px) * 1.20

          explore(myPicture)
```

Above is my code! Im trying to make an image and make it whiter with whiteBalance().

Heres my planning

Calculation of grey value at reference point – The grey value of the pixel is the average of its red, green and blue values. For instance, in the example the RGB values of the reference point at this stage would be 151, 161 and 137. Therefore, the grey value should be 149.66...

Calculation of R, G, B adjustment factors – We want the RGB values of the reference point to be turned in to the grey value calculated above. For this, we divide the grey value by the individual red, green, blue values at the reference point and get the adjustment factor.

So thats the scenario, after that the image will be displayed brighter, what can i do, this current code glitches and makes the windows pop up 100 times, literally!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your code you ask for x and y but not use it to calculate the grey value? Also, where are those numbers come from? (the one you use to make new red, green and blue value?)

I'll explain every step but don't just copy the code, try to understand it and write it again. That how people learn to program. Good luck!

Use this to pick a file, make it your picture and display it for comparison later.

```
def whiteBalance():
 file = pickAFile()
 pic = makePicture(file)
 explore(pic)
```

Then ask the user for a reference point in your picture

```
x = requestInteger ("Please specify X-coordinate")
y = requestInteger ("Please specify Y-coordinate")
```

Then get the RGB value of that specific pixel the user just gave you

```
pixel = getPixelAt(pic,x,y)
```

Pull R,G,B value from that pixel to use for calculation of the gray value

```
red = getRed(pixel)
green = getGreen(pixel)
blue = getBlue(pixel)
average = (red+green+blue)/3.00
```

Then calculate R, G, B adjustment factors.

```
redadj = average /red
greenadj = average /green
blueadj = average /blue
```

Now you can use a loop to apply the change to the entire immage.

```
for r in getPixels(pic):
  value = getRed(r)
  setRed(r, (value* redadj))

for g in getPixels(pic):
  value = getGreen(g)
  setGreen(g, (value* greenadj))

for b in getPixels(pic):
  value = getBlue(b)
  setBlue(b, (value* blueadj))
```

Then now you can display your edited image with explore(pic).
Just pay attention to the indentation, that's why you're getting a lot of windows popping up.

Comment: Thanks, I've done this code but it seems to just load and not show any picture

Comment: how do i make the r, g ,b loops into one loop?

Comment: You have to add explore or repaint at the end of the code to show the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm on the same assignment as you.

Your problem is that the explore() command at the bottom is inside your loops. So each time it loops you are producing another image. Just need to bring it out so it executes once the loops are completed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fully working code:

```
def whiteBalance():
 file = pickAFile()
 pic = makePicture(file)
 explore(pic) #open original picture for comparison 

 #Pick a picture then ask for a pixel in the picture.

 x = requestInteger ("Please specify X-coordinate")
 y = requestInteger ("Please specify Y-coordinate")

 pixel = getPixelAt(pic,x,y)

 #Get the RGB value of the given pixel.

 red = getRed(pixel)
 green = getGreen(pixel)
 blue = getBlue(pixel)

 #The grey value of the pixel is the average of its red, green and blue values.

 average = (red+green+blue)/3.00

 #Calculation of R, G, B adjustment factors.

 redadj = average /red
 greenadj = average /green
 blueadj = average /blue

 #Adjustment of the entire image.

 for r in getPixels(pic):
  value = getRed(r)
  setRed(r, (value* redadj))

 for g in getPixels(pic):
  value = getGreen(g)
  setGreen(g, (value* greenadj))

 for b in getPixels(pic):
  value = getBlue(b)
  setBlue(b, (value* blueadj))

 #Display the edited image.

 explore(pic)
```

There're many way to make the RGB loop into one loop, maybe something like this:

```
 for p in getPixels(pic):
  newRed = getRed(p)*redadj
  newBlue = getBlue(p)*blueadj
  newGreen = getGreen(p)*greenadj
  setRed(p,newRed)
  setGreen(p,newGreen)
  setBlue(p,newBlue)
```

Comment: Thank you so much , you've been a great help, just one last question, how would i do this exact same function, but ask the user to specify a rectangular region?

Answer (score 0):

think of a rectangle using the top left corner being x1 and y1 and the bottom left of the rectangle being x2 and y2
 these four points should be able to make a region for selection like you have already in your code for x and y